# How to filter an aggregation based on the values of top hits?

Tags: elasticsearch

The mapping of the elastic search documents are as follows:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "vote_id": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "song_id": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "byte"
            },
            "timestamp": {
                "type": "date"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to aggregate these votes such that it returns songs that you AND your friends like.

So far, I have buckets of songs that you and your friends like, but some buckets may be songs that only your friends like.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "terms": {
                    "user_id": ["you and your friend ids"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "songs": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "song_id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": "length of you and your friends",
                        "_source": ["vote_id", "song_id", "user_id", "type", "timestamp"]
                    }
                },
                "more_than_one": {
                    "bucket_selector": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                            "count": "_count"
                        },
                        "script": "params.count > 1"
                    }
                }
            },
            
        }
    }
}
```

I want to filter the buckets such that at least one of the documents in the top hits has your user id.

This is the current response

```
"aggregations": {
    "songs": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "doc_count": 5,
          "docs": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_id": "ivotNtFBb9TCEfpk3S54q6gcMbjZB82Xc1_ZCgA6kYsUmvk",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:56.118207343Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr8keSbPjX9ZqFhX4Dei4G",
                    "vote_id": "ivotNtFBb9TCEfpk3S54q6gcMbjZB82Xc1_ZCgA6kYsUmvk"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotEFcqOlCL5htJZJ43NslAP555DaPj0Dgkcay_Ml2jAT4",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:52.143988883Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr18wnuxsy8oVVK3Xic4Sy",
                    "vote_id": "ivotEFcqOlCL5htJZJ43NslAP555DaPj0Dgkcay_Ml2jAT4"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotToZ-0iBiM_zF5TP1Shj5C29WV3U0ibedlxvcQccimeo",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:50.178450007Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrKDxnm75fADEpusbmx5JM",
                    "vote_id": "ivotToZ-0iBiM_zF5TP1Shj5C29WV3U0ibedlxvcQccimeo"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotAHBPual232E12ggibhr6GfQ5E3f9Ryov0gYKGrIRB0Y",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:52.886305925Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrJG4GwkWa6Y70LPkuNCPg",
                    "vote_id": "ivotAHBPual232E12ggibhr6GfQ5E3f9Ryov0gYKGrIRB0Y"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivot7a8rWunlFu_q5St44PYDeNelLq4bsxr9wzYP9D80wxE",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:49.031694548Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrxunBXT1UD0IrvjqjgWaj",
                    "vote_id": "ivot7a8rWunlFu_q5St44PYDeNelLq4bsxr9wzYP9D80wxE"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                }
              ],
              "max_score": 1,
              "total": {
                "relation": "eq",
                "value": 5
              }
            }
          },
          "key": "isngVOkuaMqJTu6eQDj73gDYGObUus3g5Qp8"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 4,
          "docs": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_id": "ivot9_2eQ_3eqU7SXQBnLWGQwFI5DE99Naf8wYbFNFrj1lk",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isng4hKgRPQvH0YhtBy5GaUqgCdwDoVhJuf6",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:55.761587927Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr8keSbPjX9ZqFhX4Dei4G",
                    "vote_id": "ivot9_2eQ_3eqU7SXQBnLWGQwFI5DE99Naf8wYbFNFrj1lk"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotUZRVSKzGbmlP4LlmBkMwMM8xcR4nGTE9KNpysVR0vXQ",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isng4hKgRPQvH0YhtBy5GaUqgCdwDoVhJuf6",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:52.555377592Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr18wnuxsy8oVVK3Xic4Sy",
                    "vote_id": "ivotUZRVSKzGbmlP4LlmBkMwMM8xcR4nGTE9KNpysVR0vXQ"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivot5Wj8pIkbO0JOV_5s2PqEvZU3sy0WSYYUSlgs2Qizfo8",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isng4hKgRPQvH0YhtBy5GaUqgCdwDoVhJuf6",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:49.756332674Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrKDxnm75fADEpusbmx5JM",
                    "vote_id": "ivot5Wj8pIkbO0JOV_5s2PqEvZU3sy0WSYYUSlgs2Qizfo8"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivot8QNCJGsNtRiZYa-QMTUHEh5MHHHr4EKJsXm4UTAwJkg",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isng4hKgRPQvH0YhtBy5GaUqgCdwDoVhJuf6",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:53.26319105Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrJG4GwkWa6Y70LPkuNCPg",
                    "vote_id": "ivot8QNCJGsNtRiZYa-QMTUHEh5MHHHr4EKJsXm4UTAwJkg"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                }
              ],
              "max_score": 1,
              "total": {
                "relation": "eq",
                "value": 4
              }
            }
          },
          "key": "isng4hKgRPQvH0YhtBy5GaUqgCdwDoVhJuf6"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 3,
          "docs": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_id": "ivotoCfJc_q5vuY27KmvZUo8s4tilI57_xJoPXqfSeJTikg",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngHAVCux40BgjGVZuAwZlTiEjVQFxuxurc",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:50.527352591Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrL8FCabxg1YCeaakcVXG5",
                    "vote_id": "ivotoCfJc_q5vuY27KmvZUo8s4tilI57_xJoPXqfSeJTikg"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotStjKDIRy6vfaO5dNws4wGPELywPRgg7D7uSavatfIEo",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngHAVCux40BgjGVZuAwZlTiEjVQFxuxurc",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:51.733375716Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr18wnuxsy8oVVK3Xic4Sy",
                    "vote_id": "ivotStjKDIRy6vfaO5dNws4wGPELywPRgg7D7uSavatfIEo"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotUHj_Ebh-xIqqPJNEdWAuc_JO_mcVVG8F9wM67bJ7_6A",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngHAVCux40BgjGVZuAwZlTiEjVQFxuxurc",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:48.60900159Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrxunBXT1UD0IrvjqjgWaj",
                    "vote_id": "ivotUHj_Ebh-xIqqPJNEdWAuc_JO_mcVVG8F9wM67bJ7_6A"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                }
              ],
              "max_score": 1,
              "total": {
                "relation": "eq",
                "value": 3
              }
            }
          },
          "key": "isngHAVCux40BgjGVZuAwZlTiEjVQFxuxurc"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 3,
          "docs": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_id": "ivotE5xO9hZGLhrS2sL1mgf5UbcHtf_5qAwbrp3QwEtf4zk",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngOMnUKFVT1cKsH6Q9JfpF3WEZ4H4iU75W",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:54.99023451Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusre80pxIMFB XfF61SHlCiz",
                    "vote_id": "ivotE5xO9hZGLhrS2sL1mgf5UbcHtf_5qAwbrp3QwEtf4zk"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotI0OCI6gz6oEV94hgvjZmGB-qA4n-EigirDRJpgeZt68",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngOMnUKFVT1cKsH6Q9JfpF3WEZ4H4iU75W",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:50.952366924Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr3oWy3mxsBWu6CU4mlw5L",
                    "vote_id": "ivotI0OCI6gz6oEV94hgvjZmGB-qA4n-EigirDRJpgeZt68"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotm7GrIeyWRHamPXF9klzTZ0La8H4evCgWkCTIpx8rLl4",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngOMnUKFVT1cKsH6Q9JfpF3WEZ4H4iU75W",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:48.234881506Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrCbCltg4nzv0b2JfUbyhj",
                    "vote_id": "ivotm7GrIeyWRHamPXF9klzTZ0La8H4evCgWkCTIpx8rLl4"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                }
              ],
              "max_score": 1,
              "total": {
                "relation": "eq",
                "value": 3
              }
            }
          },
          "key": "isngOMnUKFVT1cKsH6Q9JfpF3WEZ4H4iU75W"
        },
        {
          "doc_count": 2,
          "docs": {
            "hits": {
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_id": "ivotGWwrgPehs9s7ZwZACzkVNp4-_SUaUu3noUKyBH8IBnw",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngfMv4IemhtjXX78LTqxKFBc1VMeUz6And",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:53.785333717Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusrYvNFTaTg4RBNBxG63nkY",
                    "vote_id": "ivotGWwrgPehs9s7ZwZACzkVNp4-_SUaUu3noUKyBH8IBnw"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                },
                {
                  "_id": "ivotrWG5cy6vEbe0N4JO4IKzHZyahOlkyPctCdrBnBu-v9Q",
                  "_index": "votes-index",
                  "_score": 1,
                  "_source": {
                    "song_id": "isngfMv4IemhtjXX78LTqxKFBc1VMeUz6And",
                    "timestamp": "2022-07-08T19:41:51.303745591Z",
                    "type": 1,
                    "user_id": "iusr18wnuxsy8oVVK3Xic4Sy",
                    "vote_id": "ivotrWG5cy6vEbe0N4JO4IKzHZyahOlkyPctCdrBnBu-v9Q"
                  },
                  "_type": "_doc"
                }
              ],
              "max_score": 1,
              "total": {
                "relation": "eq",
                "value": 2
              }
            }
          },
          "key": "isngfMv4IemhtjXX78LTqxKFBc1VMeUz6And"
        }
      ],
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0
    }
  }
```

I want to filter out the aggregate hits that have documents with your own id

Comment: I could not reproduce, could you give an sample that show the error ?

Comment: i don't get an error, but i will post the current and desired responses

Comment: My bad, yes you don't have error, but we need the data so we can reproduce